# can TBinary Protocol decode thrifter encoded data?

Tags: go, thrift, thrift-protocol

currently I have many go structs generated by thrift and I want to fill the real data in to them and send to server. Server will use TBinaryProtocol to decode data.

thrifter: https://github.com/thrift-iterator/go
TBinaryProtocol https://people.apache.org/~thejas/thrift-0.9/javadoc/org/apache/thrift/protocol/TBinaryProtocol.Factory.html

client: data := thrifter.Marshal(interface{}) -> send() ->
server: decode(factory.getProtocol(buf))

Comment: If it cannot, is there any for go-thrift (https://godoc.org/github.com/apache/thrift/lib/go/thrift) to serialize a interface struct?

Comment: Why don't you just try it?